# django messages after dataframe export to excel

Tags: django, message

I have a Django view that perform a long qry in the back-end.  Once the qry result is available, it exports the data to a csv file.

I am using this logic, which is working fine:

```
response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')  # Format response as a CSV
filename = 'some_file_name' + '.csv'
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'  # Name the CSV response
df.to_csv(response, encoding='utf-8', index=False)
return response
```

I need to add a response message that displays on the current page without needing to refresh the page:

for that I have the following:

```
if df is None or df.shape[0] ==0:
    messages.warning(request, 'failure message.')
else:
     messages.success(request, 'success message.')
```

and in the html I have:

```
{% if messages %}
    <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
            <li{% if message.tags %} class="{{ message.tags }}"{% endif %} id="export_messages">{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

The problem that I am facing is that the message appears only if I refresh the page after export button is clicked and the file is successfully exported.

I am looking for an advise or guidance how to make the message appears right after the button click event.

Please note that the action is a form event (not Ajax call)

```
<form class="default_form" method="POST" action="my_action">
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: your code look right. try to add message before return without conditional to look for a possible error in your conditional.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback.  I did what you suggested, but still no luck.   My form is not a Django Model form.  It is a standard HTML form with tags names passed on to the view.  In the view, I set the messages as mentioned earlier.  Once the form is submitted, the csv EXCEL download works .  But the messages do not appear on the form without a refresh.  the problem with the refresh is that all user selection are reset, which is something I am trying to avoid.  Please advise if another solution is possible.   Thank you